# How to see the last deployment date on azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a pipeline defined on `azure devops` which deploys (upload using PowerShell) a `Azure Function` to azure. The problem is that I can't find on the azure portal where to see the last updated date of the function.

Is there a way to see that?

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the azure function has been deployed in last n period of time by navigating to

> Azure Function --> Platform Features --> Activity Log

In the activity log, change the "Timespan" and add another filter as '**Operation**' and the associated value as '**Create or Update Web App**' and '**Update Web App Configuration**'.
[image]

Also, at at any point of time you can navigate to KUDU site: [https://webappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole] and can check the file timestamps.